# Table1 Left Join Table2 Minus (join Data)

Tags: mysql, sql

**TABLE 1) m_conservationsetting**

```
FacilityId   Unit   CategoryId
    1          1        1
    1          1        2
    1          1        3
    1          2        1
    1          2        2
    2          1        1
    2          2        1
```

Unique Key(FacilityId  Unit CategoryId)

**TABLE 2) l_maintelog**

```
FacilityId   Unit  CategoryId  Status
    1          1        1         0
    1          1        2         1
    1          1        3         0
    1          2        1         0
    2          1        1         0
    2          2        1         0
```

**Result :**

```
FacilityId   Unit   CategoryId
    1          2        2
```

Table1 need to be left Joined  with Table2 and it should ommit the join results and show only table1 data as results.
Table1 LeftJoin Table2 - (join Data) for the below query. The condition for getting result is to check the status=0 for the record in Table2

```
SELECT cs.FacilityId,Cs.Unit,cs.CategoryId 
FROM m_conservationsetting cs 
LEFT JOIN l_maintelog ml 
ON cs.FacilityId=ml.FacilityId and cs.Unit=ml.Unit
WHERE ml.Status=0 
GROUP BY cs.CategoryId
```

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT JOIN` if you only want rows that have a specific status in table 2?

Comment: If you use `GROUP BY cs.CategoryId` you can't get two rows in the result with the same `CategoryId`.

Comment: The result you want is not just the values that are not the result of left join check again you have one value that is the left join result 1,1,2

Comment: I can't figure out how your results relate to the input. Everything I've tried returns at least 4 rows.

Comment: @BAmur soory for the wromg result i have corrected it ...

Comment: When you require "it should omit the join results" - is that to be read as "omit the **INNER** join results"? If so, that should basically be `SELECT FacilityId, Unit, CategoryId FROM m_conservationsetting LEFT JOIN l_maintelog USING (FacilityId, Unit, CategoryId) WHERE l_maintelog.Status IS NULL;`. This, however, would contradict the requirement to check for **l_maintelog.status = 0**.

Comment: @Abecee you can add `0 Status` when selecting from table1, and it will left join in right way considering status=0 from table2 ... I've added answer

Comment: @madzohan OP requires "The condition for getting result is to check the status=0 for the record in Table2", which your solution doesn't seem to provide: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cc06/7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to take those records that are not in result of `left join` so do like this:

```
SELECT t.* FROM m_conservationsetting AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT cs.FacilityId,Cs.Unit,cs.CategoryId 
    FROM m_conservationsetting AS cs 
    LEFT JOIN l_maintelog ml on
       (cs.FacilityId=ml.FacilityId and cs.Unit=ml.Unit)
    WHERE ml.Status=0 
    group by cs.CategoryId
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but qurey not giving expected results.

Comment: @neo could you tell me the result that this query bring for the same data you provided here, because i have not tested, and if you can please make a `fiddle`.

Answer (score 2):

Only left join is enough to get the result.

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare @table1 Table
(
     FacilityId         Int
    ,Unit               Int
    ,CategoryId         Int
)

Declare @table2 Table
(
     FacilityId         Int
    ,Unit               Int
    ,CategoryId         Int
    ,[Status]           Bit
)

Insert Into @table1(FacilityId,Unit,CategoryId) Values
 (1,1,1)
,(1,1,2)
,(1,1,3)
,(1,2,1)
,(1,2,2)
,(2,1,1)
,(2,2,1)

Insert Into @table2(FacilityId,Unit,CategoryId,[Status]) Values
 (1,1,1,0)
,(1,1,2,1)
,(1,1,3,0)
,(1,2,1,0)
,(2,1,1,0)
,(2,2,1,0)

Select  t1.*
From    @table1 As t1
        Left Join @table2 As t2 On t1.FacilityId = t2.FacilityId
            And t1.Unit = t2.Unit
            And t1.CategoryId = t2.CategoryId
Where   t2.FacilityId Is Null
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have to consider status condtion in table2(t2) whether t2.Status=0 . Then I am not able to get the above result.

Comment: In order to check for **table2.status = 0**, shouldn't there be a record `(1,2,2,0)` in **table2**? But then, what would make that record special compared to all the other ones with **table2.status = 0** (and the respective related records in **table1**)?